# HTML entities to Hex equivalent

Tags: html, xml, encoding

I have legacy xml files with html entities such as `&mdash;` etc. How can I convert this entities to hex equivalent such as `&#8212;`. Is there any easy way to do this using a batch command or something else? I am not high level programmer so any detail help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple find and replace may be all you need. Most, if not all text/code editors have a find/replace function.

Chances are that there are only a few characters strings that make up the majority of what you need to replace and fortunately, they're all pretty unique so it's unlikely that you'll have any accidental replacements.